# Getting divs in the right postion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently bought some code on code canyon (I thought it would save me some time) and for the most part it works, but I just can't get the positioning right.

Basically I need cards in a column to be able to be flipped over. The card needs to take on it's own height according to it's back & front content and also fill the width of the column.

The part that I can't seem to get right is getting the cards which need to be flipped correctly underneath each other.

This is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrThursday/53r5ev1r/4/)

At the top of the rows are supposed to 2 separate boxes which is supposed to be flip-able, followed by 4 rows which are examples how it should look.

I am sure it has something to do with

```
position: relative;
```

in the css, but I just can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position: absolute;` setting from the `.card-container .card>div` style and add

```
.card-container .card .back {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Your problem was that having `position: absolute;` on both the `.front` and `.back` divs caused the container divs to have no size. Therefore the following container divs were positioned at the same point as the previous container div.